# Adding drawable image into ActionBar.Tab

Tags: android

I'm developing Android Application.there i have to use  **Swipe Views with Tabs** .
i want to add drawable image(**non_click image**) when tabs load & press the tab there will be  another image of same tab (**click_state image**) .Please find below the code I used.please help me to do it

```
package com.example.creatingswipeviewswithtabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {


    ActionBar action_bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        action_bar=getActionBar();
        //action_bar.setBackgroundDrawable(d)
        action_bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1=action_bar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Login");

        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=action_bar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Compare Now");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=action_bar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Search");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        action_bar.addTab(tab1);
        action_bar.addTab(tab2);
        action_bar.addTab(tab3);






    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

Answer (score 5):

`tabs` is an array for `Tab` `String`s

```
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
     actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher));           
}
```

Comment: tab3.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);yap it helps me to do non click image.are there any way to put clik_image ?